# Android: SQLite: Loading Views with Data Queried by IntentService

Tags: android, android-intent, cursor, bundle, intentservice

I know that an Activity can create an intent and send it to an IntentService.

I know that the IntentService, having fulfilled a request, can send a Message back to the calling activity.

I know that the Message sent from the IntentService to the calling Activity can contain a Bundle [setData(Bundle b);]

QUESTION: Can the Message sent from an IntentService to the calling Activity contain a Bundle/Cursor of arbitrary size (let's say 169 records)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to find a way to get the data to my ListView from another thread, using this [article](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429).

Now I can both load my views from QUERYing an SQLite db AND take user input from my activity views and INSERT the data into an SQLite db using the same IntentService (one IntentService per Table in the SQLite database, not counting custom trigger classes [all activities associated with the same table use the same IntentService])!

When the IntentService responds to the calling Activity using the Message class, I stuff the Message with a Bundle containing the Serializable two-dimensional array [Bundle.putSerializable("Label",*2DArray*)] returned from the SQLite db query.

In the Activity that array is converted to an array containing a custom class with two fields, which is then bound to a custom ArrayAdapter.

Notifiers arent necessary because everytime the Activity.onResume() is called, the views are reloaded with the latest data.

Answer (score 0):

A Cursor isn't Parcelable... So it probably cannot be passed as part of a Bundle.

Usually, the pattern is for the IntentService to modify a record in a shared model (maybe a database or even a full content provider) which the Activities then observe via Loaders set to Uris of interest within that model.

And no, using Loaders with Cursor does not necessarily mean you have to write a content provider, but it does help if you do.